# Rythm: create new engine or set Language/Locale on existing engine instance per request

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

Rythm can be used as a singleton or instantiated as a normal object.
Currently I instantiate it once in a webapp in the Servlet `Init()` method. (This is almost the same as using a singleton since I'm only creating it once)

Now I need to add i18n support to my site and need to set the language dynamically before rendering.

I could do this:

```
engine.setLocale(userLocale);
engine.render(template,arguments);
```

I assume that if I use a singleton(or single instance created in the servlet) then I might get a race condition between the two statements.

1. Is this correct or is there no race condition?
2. Should I create a Rythm instance for each request?
3. Is there another way to change the language for each rendering without changing the engine state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in the latest version of rythm, you should call `engine.prepare(Locale)`, not `engine.setLocale(Locale)`;

Now to answer your questions:

> 1. Is this correct or is there no race condition?

It will NOT cause race condition because inside the code it uses `ThreadLocal` to store the render settings

> 2. Should I create a Rythm instance for each request?

Definitely **NO**

> 3. Is there another way to change the language for each rendering without changing the engine state?

Language and locale are **NOT** engine level states, they are **per request** states. However **default** language and locale could be configured at engine level

Comment: Thanks! Very clear answers! Sorry about the setLocale(). I was using engine.prepare(). Not sure where I got that from....